# Could someone explain this code to me? Concerning conditionally disabling inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Update:**
What exactly is the filter part of the checkedCount expression doing? I understand that we are getting the property names from state and calculating the length, but what is the filter portion doing?  When I remove it, everything works until "disabled" becomes true.  Then it will not go back to false.

**Original**
I am trying to accomplish what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51717797/11420464) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51717752/11420464) is doing: rendering a number of checkboxes that disables any unchecked boxes after a certain number is reached.  I was able to use what is posted to solve my problem, but I am not sure of what all is going on.

I understand that an array of inputs is being rendered, and their keys are being set to this.state.checked in order to toggle checked or unchecked. I understand that when checkedCount is greater than 1, the inputs are then disabled. I am a bit confused on the details though.  Would someone be able to break down what is going on? I'd like to wrap my head around this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: {} };

  onSelectedChange = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      checked: {
        ...previousState.checked,
        [index]: !previousState.checked[index]
      }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
    const disabled = checkedCount > 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index] || false}
            disabled={!checked[index] && disabled}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: where are u confused?

Comment: I am confused about the parts where "index" is in brackets, the ellipses before "previousState.checked" and how the checkedCount constant is being defined.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: 1) [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) 2) [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) 3) [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: look at [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and see the map function it accepts - study that. then look at [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is the filter part of the checkedCount expression doing?

```
// This part is aimed to calculate how many `input` has been selected
const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
// equals
const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => { return  checked[key] === true  })

// if `checkedCount` more than one(> 1), disabled others `input`
```

=======UPDATE=====

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: {} };

  onSelectedChange = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      checked: {
        ...previousState.checked,
        [index]: !previousState.checked[index]
      }
    }));

    // equals
    // const { checked } = this.state;
    // this.setState({
    //   ...checked,
    //   [index]: !checked[index]
    // })

    // first round
    // assume you checked first `input`
    // checkd = {}
    // checed[0] = undefined   !checed[0] === true
    // { ...{}, { 0: true } } ==> { 0: true }
    // const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
    // cuz checkedCount === 1 , so disabled is false

    // second round
    // you checked second `input`
    // checked = { 0: true }
    // checed[1] = undefined  !checed[1] === true
    // { ...{ 0: true }, { 1: true }} ==> {0: true, 1: true }

    // const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
    // cuz checkedCount > 1 , so disabled is true now
    // others `input` element's attribute disabled become true
    // example third one 
    // {!checked[2] && disabled}  ==> {!undefined && true } ==> true

  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    console.log({checked})
    // find out had checked count
    // Object.keys(checked).filter(key => { return  checked[key] === true  })
    const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
    const disabled = checkedCount > 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index] || false}
            disabled={!checked[index] && disabled}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```